# Django authenticate() not working, it keeps returning none eventhough tthe user is stored in the database

Tags: python, django-forms

i am using a custom_user model which i have made visible on django
the database is working well but to log in a user it is not working
i have tried adding request to the authenticate function but its still not working
i also included 2 print functions to check where the problem was at it was after i tried to authenticate the user

view.py

```py
def register_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponse(f"You are already authenticated as {user.email}")
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = Registration_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password1']
            print(f"Email: {email}, Password: {password}")
            user= authenticate(request,email=email, password=password)
            print(f"Account: {user}")
            if user is not None:
                # Authentication was successful; log in the user.
                login(request, user)
                destination = kwargs.get("next")
                if destination:
                    return redirect(destination)
                return redirect("home")
            else:
                # Authentication failed; handle the error or inform the user.
                context['registration_form'] = form
        #
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    #
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

forms.py

```py
class Registration_Form(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        model = Custom_user
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        try:
            user = Custom_user.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(f"Email {email} already exist")
```

models.py

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser cant be created without being a staff')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser cant be created without being allowed to be superuser ')
        return self.create_user(email,first_name,last_name,password,**other_fields)

    def create_user(self,email,first_name,last_name,password,**other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('You have not entered a email')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('No password entered')
        email= self.normalize_email(email)
        user= self.model(email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,**other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class Custom_user(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

i am open to help .if there is anything you wish to know in regards to the source code i can provide it

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. `UserManager` as I see it should be in serializers file and not in models. Secondly `UserManager` check for email and password which are required to create a user, so it's not good practice. Can you give us also `settings.py`? Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?